# Add an IntegerField to a Datefield in a Django template

Tags: django, datetime, date

I'm trying to display the expiry date of a bonus from within a Django template. At the moment the opening_date is stored as a datefield and we store the bonus term as an integerfield. Unfortunately just trying to add the bonus term to the opening date fails and the furthest I have got so far is:

```
{{product_form.instance.opening_date|add:product_form.instance.bonus_term}}
```

I have tried just adding it to the month but unfortunately I need the whole date returned to display.

For a better idea of what I want is say the opening date was 01/01/2012 and the bonus term was 12, I want to display the expiry date of 01/01/2013. I realise this is probably better off being in the database but due to the way it has been previously set up there is a large amount of existing data that wouldn't have it.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to write your own template filter or add another context variable, though you might be able to format the datetime field to a string then use add to concatenate your text

Comment: Thanks, I knew I was missing a feature of Django that could be used.

Comment: When you have a solution, come back and post it ;)

Comment: danihp seems to have a nicer method this time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that, for your scenario, the most elegant solution is to create a [model method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-methods) in your model that calcule expire date, then call the method in template:

In model:

```
class product(models.Model): 
    opening_date = ...
    bonus_term = ...
    def expire_date( self ):
         return self.opening_date + timedelta( days = self.bonus_term )
```

In template:

```
{{product_form.instance.expire_date}}
```

I'm sure that you will call this method in more other lines of your code.

Comment: perfect, the only changes I made was to use relativedelta instead of timedelta code: return self.opening_date+relativedelta(months = +self.bonus_term)

Thanks a lot